# error A2013: .MODEL must precede this directive

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm, irvine32

Tinkering around with MASM a bit, and I have no idea what these errors mean, or if I'm writing this code close to correctly.  As it is written currently, it should just be greeting the user, asking for two numbers and saying goodbye (trying to get a skeleton working before doing any calculations or anything special).

```
INCLUDELIB Irvine32.inc ;  Note: line number 7


.data
userName    BYTE    33 DUP(0)   ;string to be entered by user
firstNumber DWORD   ?           ;integer to be entered by user
secondNumber    DWORD     ?         ;integer to be entered by user
intro_1     BYTE        "Elementary Arithmetic by Marshall Todt", 0
intro_2     BYTE        "Enter 2 numbers, and I'll show you the sum, difference,", 0
intro_3     BYTE        "product, quotient, and remainder.", 0
prompt_1        BYTE        "Enter the first integer: ", 0
prompt_2        BYTE        "Enter the second integer: ",0
goodBye     BYTE        "Impressed?  Bye!", 0

.code
main PROC

;Introduction
    mov     edx, OFFSET intro_1 
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    move        edx, OFFSET intro_2
    call WriteString
    call CrLF
    move        edx, OFFSET intro_3
    call WriteString
    call CrLF

;Get the data
    mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_1
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadInt
    mov     firstNumber, eax
    mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_2
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadInt
    mov     secondNumber, eax



;Say "Good-bye"
    mov     edx, OFFSET goodBye
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    exit    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

END main
```

These are the errors i am getting:

```
Error   1   error A2013: .MODEL must precede this directive c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   10  1   Assignment1
Error   2   error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   11  1   Assignment1
Error   3   error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   12  1   Assignment1
Error   4   error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   13  1   Assignment1
Error   5   error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   14  1   Assignment1
Error   6   error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   15  1   Assignment1
Error   7   error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   16  1   Assignment1
Error   8   error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   17  1   Assignment1
Error   9   error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   18  1   Assignment1
Error   10  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   19  1   Assignment1
Error   11  error A2013: .MODEL must precede this directive c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   21  1   Assignment1
Error   12  error A2034: must be in segment block : main    c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   22  1   Assignment1
Error   13  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   25  1   Assignment1
Error   14  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   26  1   Assignment1
Error   15  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   27  1   Assignment1
Error   16  error A2008: syntax error : edx c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   28  1   Assignment1
Error   17  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   29  1   Assignment1
Error   18  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   30  1   Assignment1
Error   19  error A2008: syntax error : edx c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   31  1   Assignment1
Error   20  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   32  1   Assignment1
Error   21  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   33  1   Assignment1
Error   22  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   36  1   Assignment1
Error   23  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   37  1   Assignment1
Error   24  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   38  1   Assignment1
Error   25  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   39  1   Assignment1
Error   26  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   40  1   Assignment1
Error   27  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   41  1   Assignment1
Error   28  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   42  1   Assignment1
Error   29  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   43  1   Assignment1
Error   30  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   48  1   Assignment1
Error   31  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   49  1   Assignment1
Error   32  error A2034: must be in segment block   c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   50  1   Assignment1
Error   33  error A2008: syntax error : exit    c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   51  1   Assignment1
Error   34  error A1010: unmatched block nesting : main c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm   52  1   Assignment1
Error   35  error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Assignment1.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaAssignment1.asm" exited with code 1.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets  49  6   Assignment1
```

Comment: I added:
    .model flat
    .486

to the code, but now I'm getting an error: 
Error 1 error A2008: syntax error : edx c:\Users\Marshall\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Assignment1\Assignment1.asm 29 1 Assignment1

Comment: Another stupid question, where in the visual studio heirarchy should I move irvine32.inc so that it can actually find it without adding additional pathing?

Comment: fixed it by copying everything into the working directory, so answered my own question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `.model flat` at the beginning of the code - and probably `.486` before that as well. I *think* that will fix almost all of your problems.

Comment: That did bypass those errors, but now I'm getting different ones.  Appended in comment above.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: different topic, new question. Just ask a new question. Doesn't help future internauts to find the answer to a question that was changed by the OP.

Answer (score -2):

You can also avoid this if you use x64 as the Platform instead of x86. As you are using the 64 bit x registers in your code maybe you are coding for x64!!!

Comment: I don't see any use of `rdx` or other 64-bit registers here.  This is clearly putting addresses into 32-bit registers, like `mov     edx, OFFSET intro_1`.  I would not suggest assembling this as 64-bit code because the Irvine32 library itself is (unsurprisingly) 32-bit.