# Errors in MASM Assembly Compilation: ".MODEL must precede this directive" and "must be in segment block"

Tags: assembly, masm

I am working on some assembly code that defines a simple empty function using MASM:

```
.CODE

option casemap:none

public asmFunc

asm Func PROC
    ret
asmFunc ENDP

END
```

When I attempt to compile the code using:

```
> ml /c test.asm
```

in the terminal, it gives me the following errors:

```
Assembling: test2.asm
test2.asm(1) : error A2013: .MODEL must precede this directive
test2.asm(7) : error A2008: syntax error : Func
test2.asm(8) : error A2034: must be in segment block
test2.asm(9) : fatal error A1010: unmatched block nesting : asmFunc
```

Can anyone help me understand what the issues are?

Comment: Please make more obvious which kind of help you expect of the c++ experts you lure here by tagging C++. Their helpful mood might otherwise suffer.

Comment: You might find this info helpful for making your post more accessable https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and [ask] and [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error A2013: .MODEL must precede this directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517215/error-a2013-model-must-precede-this-directive)

Comment: Before creating a [.CODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-code?view=msvc-170) segment, you must inform the assembler what model you are using.  This affects a number of things, such as what instructions are available, how naming is done, etc.  For 64 bit code, there's only 1 standard, so nothing needs to be done.  But for 32 bit code, you must use the [.MODEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-model?view=msvc-170) directive.  Also, is your function `asm Func` or `asmFunc`?  You should pick one name and using it consistently.